# OAuth 2.0 authorize workflow for third-party apps

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I am implementing an App Store for my application where third-party developers can build there own apps based on my API. I have everything working and understand the concepts of OAuth 2.0, but I don't see how an external app can have timeless access with an access code that expires after one hour. Now you can use a refresh token to request a new one, but that one expires after some time too.

So how can an external app continuously connect to my API when the user of that app allows it only once?

My authorization codes expire after 10 minutes, the access tokens after 1 hour and the refresh tokens after 2 weeks.

I don't see how the app can retrieve data after those periods of time without the user re-allowing/re-installing the application through oauth.

How are bigger companies like Facebook etc. approaching this? Do they have an access token that never expires?

Comment: Can it be that I my refresh token don't need an expiration date?

Comment: Usually refresh tokens will have a bigger lifetime or not expire at all.

Comment: My refresh tokens expire after 2 weeks, just checked it. After reading some information about how Facebook does this, they seem to use persistent access tokens. Is this correct and safe?

Comment: I am thinking to have my refresh tokens to never expire, so the third party apps can always issue a fresh access token, which will expire after 1-2 hours again. I think that is the safest way to go, do you agree @JoãoAngelo?

Comment: I started the comment, but it was getting pretty long so added an answer with my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, the general recommendation when using bearer tokens is that their lifetime should be reduced in order to mitigate the impact of an access token being compromised.

On the other hand, asking the user credentials every hour or so would be an UX nightmare so OAuth 2.0 has the notion of [refresh tokens](https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/) which will normally have a longer lifetime allowing the application to request a new access token without requiring user intervention.

I'm unfamiliar with the implementation details around Facebook persistent tokens so I won't comment on that, but they are most likely safe. However, you're not Facebook, so my recommendation would be for you to follow public standards like OAuth 2.0/OpenID Connect instead of trying to provide a customized approach.

Regarding your comment about refresh tokens that never expire, it's an acceptable solution, but their lifetime is just one part of the equation. You should consider if they are multi-use or single-use, they can only be used by the client application that they were issued to, they should not be used by browser-based applications due to the difficulties of ensuring secure storage, etc.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I will go for a long lived refresh tokens (never expire), since those will be exchanged server to server, no client.

Comment: as a slight improvement over that you could renew the refresh token as well as the access token on each refresh token request

Comment: I agree with this answer. Another good practice is to provide a revocation endpoint in case of compromission of a refresh token

Comment: This discussion is helpful for someone like me who is new to OAuth. Thanks for that. I have a question posted at below link to get bit more understanding, is it possible to provide some insight there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620839/what-is-the-right-oauth-workflow-for-3rd-party-rest-apis